# Show video as part of the post?

Tags: theme-development, add-theme-support

I am doing a post in wordpress, but I want to put a video as part of the post. I mean, I have a paragraph but after the paragraph I want to put a video. I did put it as media, but it just shows a link and if I clic on the link it downloads the file, and I just want to play the video, not to download it. What can I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I want to *embed* a video on a WP post I use the html5 `<video>` tag. It's very simple to put into the html code and is much like the `<img>` tag. [W3Schools breaks it down for dummies.](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp) Here is their sample code:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
       <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
       <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the video is on the [embeds list](https://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds) then you should be able to just paste a link and it will appear. Like this:

`https://youtu.be/BjJ1A-1JKh0`

You can also use a shortcode for a little more control like this:

`[embed width="123" height="456"]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ[/embed]`